# How do I find all occurences of each letter in a string/text file?

Tags: perl, text

So for instance the output should be something like

There are 4 instances of A 
There are 0 instances of B
There are 1 instances of C
.
.
There are 9 instances of Z

I have a general Idea of what to do, but how do I "optimize" my code so that I don't have to write everything out? In other words I'd like help writing a loop that will write all the "there are x instances of (letter)" output and I'm looking for a way to incorporate "a..z" instead of looking through each letter meticulously.

Comment: This is not a real question. There are too many possible answers. [**Learn how to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

```
my $str = "AABBBCCCCCCCDDDDDDDDDDDDD";

my %counts;
++$counts{ uc($_) } for split //, $str;

for my $char (sort keys %counts) {
  print "There are $counts{$char} instances of $char\n";
}
```